# Kusto - Last row by timestamp for every series

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table where messages are logged, for every operation there are several messages with timestamp.
I need to get the last message for every operation_id.

Example data:

```
timestamp                  | operation_id | message 
---------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------
10/2/2019, 10:00:10.000 AM |    1         | message (last msg for this operation id)
10/2/2019, 10:00:00.000 AM |    1         | message
10/2/2019, 10:00:03.000 AM |    2         | message (last msg for this operation id)
10/2/2019, 10:00:00.000 AM |    3         | message
10/2/2019, 10:00:00.000 AM |    2         | message
10/2/2019, 10:00:15.000 AM |    3         | message (last msg for this operation id)
```

Desired output:

```
timestamp                  | operation_id | message 
---------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------
10/2/2019, 10:00:10.000 AM |    1         | message (last msg for this operation id)
10/2/2019, 10:00:03.000 AM |    2         | message (last msg for this operation id)
10/2/2019, 10:00:15.000 AM |    3         | message (last msg for this operation id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the aggregation function [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction)

Note that the applicable examples are in the arg_min() doc...